# Scrapy authenticating with aspx page

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, scrapy

I'm trying to find the best way of login in to a site using aspx pages and then redirecting to a new page within that site to start scraping. I'm confident the scraping part is working as I have tried it out on a mocked up page but I've not done authentication before and I'm finding that the site is redirecting to a search url. The only thing I can think is happening is scrapy is triggering the search box?

The site is howdidido.co.uk and my spider code is as follows:

```
from scrapy.spider       import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector     import Selector
from pgcmh.items         import PgcmhItem
from scrapy.http         import Request
from scrapy.http         import FormRequest
from scrapy.selector     import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider

class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'pgcmh'
    allowed_domains     = ["howdidido.co.uk"]
    login_page = 'http://howdidido.co.uk/Widgets.aspx'
    start_urls = ["http://howdidido.co.uk/ClubDetails.aspx?section=55&pagesection=handicaplist&cid=74"]

    def start_requests(self):
        return self.init_request()

    def init_request(self):
        return [Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)]

    def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'username': 'dummyemail', 'password': 'dummypass'}, callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        if "Logout" in response.body:
                for url in self.start_urls:
                        yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
        else:
                self.log("Could not log in...")

    def make_requests_from_url(url):
        sel = Selector(response)
        for tablerow in sel.css('table.basictable tr'):
            item = PgcmhItem()
            item["name"] = tablerow.xpath('td[1]').extract()
            item["handicap"] = tablerow.xpath('td[2]').extract()
            item["exact"] = tablerow.xpath('td[3]').extract()
            item["category"] = tablerow.xpath('td[4]').extract()
            yield item
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'ctl00$WrappedContent$txtUser': 'dummyemail', 'ctl00$WrappedContent$txtPass': 'dummypass'}, callback=self.check_login_response)
```